# SQL Query to get one "row" up in table

Tags: sql-server

I need to get a list of results from a table in SQL, such that I need the row with a date value immediately previous to the ones which would be selected by a where statement. In the image below, I'd write:

```
select * from Table t where Color = 'blue'
```

but I don't know how to get the rows above the blue rows that are highlighted. The example is Excel, but only for the ease of generating an example. "Blue" in real life is a lot more joins and data, but for a minimally complete example, this works. Assume Date is not always sorted by datetime, but I always want the entry immediately before the "blue" entry, datetime wise.

[image]

Comment: Are there duplicate dates?

Comment: If you have a key that you can reliably sort on to give you the order then you can use `lag` to get the previous row

Comment: There is no key, and there is no possibility of duplicate date times.

Comment: If there are no duplicate `DATETIME`s, then it sounds like they are the key...

Answer (score 3):

With UNION ALL if there are no duplicate dates:

```
select * from Table where Color = 'blue'
union all
select * from Table t 
where 
  t.Color is null 
  and
  (
    select color from Table where date = (
      select min(date) from Table where date > t.date)
  ) = 'blue'
order by date
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to add a unique identified to the rows, such as an integer ID?

If you are able to reliably establish the ID of the blue rows, you could then query blueRowID - 1. This would seem the most straightforward method for resolving the problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @forpas, but using `LEAD`:

```
WITH 
    -- sample data (using dt as the column name to avoid 
    - using reserved words)
    t(dt, color) AS
    (
        SELECT '2019-02-15 10:31:30.993', NULL UNION ALL
        SELECT '2019-02-15 17:15:46.910', 'blue' UNION ALL
        SELECT '2019-02-16 10:21:22.793', NULL UNION ALL
        SELECT '2019-02-19 10:30:34.827', NULL UNION ALL
        SELECT '2019-02-20 09:00:51.127', 'blue' UNION ALL
        SELECT '2019-02-20 09:00:58.767', NULL UNION ALL
        SELECT '2019-02-20 10:30:42.757', NULL UNION ALL
        SELECT '2019-02-21 09:35:54.819', NULL UNION ALL
        SELECT '2019-02-22 09:59:42.813', 'blue'
    ),
    WithLead(dt, color, next_dt) AS
    (
        SELECT *,
            LEAD(dt) OVER (ORDER BY dt ASC)
        FROM t
    )
SELECT * FROM t WHERE color = 'blue'
UNION ALL
SELECT WithLead.dt, WithLead.color
FROM WithLead
    INNER JOIN t AS NextRow ON
        NextRow.dt = WithLead.next_dt
WHERE NextRow.color = 'blue'
ORDER BY dt
```

Note that the `ORDER BY` at the end is not strictly necessary, but gives you the order that you want in your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER to get them ordered and then pick the one directly above it.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ([Date] DATE,Color VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @t([Date],Color) SELECT '12/31/2019',''
INSERT INTO @t([Date],Color) SELECT '01/01/2019',''
INSERT INTO @t([Date],Color) SELECT '01/02/2019','blue'
INSERT INTO @t([Date],Color) SELECT '01/03/2019',''
INSERT INTO @t([Date],Color) SELECT '01/04/2019',''
INSERT INTO @t([Date],Color) SELECT '01/05/2019','blue'


SELECT
    *
FROM (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date] ASC) AS [Row] from @t
) SetA
WHERE Color = 'blue'
OR SetA.[Row] IN (
    SELECT [Row]-1 FROM (
        select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date] ASC) AS [Row] from @t
    )a 
    WHERE Color = 'blue'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take it step by step -- if you use CTEs like shown below it is very easy to test, at any point you can just do a select of one of the CTEs to verify it is correct.

```
WITH WITH_INDEX AS
(
   select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS RN 
   from Table t 
), BLUE AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM WITH_INDEX
  where Color = 'blue'
)
SELECT *
FROM BLUE

UNION ALL

SELECT WITH_INDEX.*
FROM WITH_INDEX 
JOIN BLUE ON WITH_INDEX.RN = BLUE.RN - 1
```